# Mysql master/slave setup - what users do i need?

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

I am currently setting up an master and 2 slaves (performance read queries) - Master -> 1 Slave works already. But now I want to add a second slave, I can not connect tho. Do I have to create a second user for that?

like so

```
grant replication slave on *.* TO {slave2}@'{192.168.2.12}' identified by '{mypass}';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

or should it work with the same user?

I guess I know the answer already, since it is bound to the IP 192.168.2.12 - but anyway - for internal testing set this just to 0.0.0.0 / % ?

Comment: why you don't use only one user for all the slaves?

Answer (score 0):

Can you connect to this server from slave ?
You can check this via telnet:

```
telnet {master_IP} {port of MySQL}
```

example:

```
telnet 192.168.2.11 3306
```

If not check you firewall, and paste (when you can) you MySQL config (my.cnf) from master and slave, and log from MySQL (replication and master).

Make sure your password for this user is shorter than 16 characters.

If you have two slave check if they are different server-id.

Comment: Yes I can connect and also choosed different server-id´s 

I could now connect to both and the slave2 started, but now I get Could not execute Update_rows_v1 event on table shopware.s_statistics_visitors; Can't find record in 's_statistics_visitors', Error_code: 1032; handler error HA_ERR_KEY_NOT_FOUND; the event's master log mariadb-bin.000035, end_log_pos 565

Could that be because of the different users?

Comment: No this is not because is different users. This is when you don't make good backup or backup is damaged or is too old or you have bad binlog/position number. Check this number or make backup again in example with innobackupex.